# Accessing two table's data SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently, I have this code:

```
SELECT Code,country.Name, city.Name,city.Population
FROM country, city 
WHERE SurfaceArea > 1000000 OR GNP > 1000000 AND GNP < 5000000
ORDER BY Code;
```

I need to list the country code (primary key of country) and the name of the countries as well as the name and population of the cities in those countries. The surface area of the country has to be greater than 1,000,000 and have a GNP between 1 million and 5 million. It seems that my current code only shows the cities that achieve the rule but none of the countries.

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify the question.  The question gives no indication of how the tables are related or which table contains the relevant columns.

Comment: The astute use of parentheses is required

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `join` condition and also you are using `OR` instead of `AND`.

```
SELECT Code,country.Name, city.Name,city.Population
  FROM country join city on city.country_code = country.code
 WHERE SurfaceArea > 1000000
   and GNP > 1000000 AND GNP < 5000000
 ORDER BY Code;
```